# Obtain house number from street address

Tags: python, regex, string

**Set-up**

I have strings containing UK format addresses, e.g. `address = '6A McCarthy Way'`.

I need to obtain the house number from the address, e.g. `house_number = '6A`

---

**Current Code**

I have the following working code,

```
position = re.search('\d+', address).start()

if position == 0:
    for i in range(0,100000):    
        if address[position + i] != ' ':
            house_number = address[:position + i + 1]    
        else:
            break
else:
    house_number = address[position:]
```

For both `address = '6A McCarthy Way'` and `address = 'McCarthy Way 6A'`, the code returns `house_number = '6A'`.

---

**Problem**

This code assumes that

- the house number will either be at the beginning or end of `address`
- the house number and address will be of the above 2 formats only – e.g. never `address = '6A, McCarthy Way'` or `address = '6 McCarthy Way'`
- there are no mistakes in `address` – e.g. never `address = '6AMcCarthy Way'`

Lastly, even if the assumptions hold for all cases, I'm not sure this is the most pythonic way of doing it.

How can I improve the code?

Comment: In general, regex will not catch "mistakes" because their nature is to expect a certain patten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re.search`

```
import re
address = '6A McCarthy Way' 
address2 = 'McCarthy Way 6A'
address3 = 'McCarthy Way 6AAAA'

print(re.search("(\d+\w*)", address).group())
print(re.search("(\d+\w*)", address2).group()) 
print(re.search("(\d+\w*)", address3).group())
```

**Output:**

```
6A
6A
6AAAA
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, works like a charm. However, I forgot an important case: `address = '6 McCarthy Way'`. How to edit your code to deal with that? `try '(\d+\w+)' except '(\d+)'`?

Comment: @LucSpan, I guess `(\d+\w*)` would do.

Comment: Just `r'\d\w*'` will suffice. Or `r'\b\d\w*'`. Or `r'(?<!\S)\d\w*'`